# how to call a function that inside a function in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to call function `f2`?

```
def f1():
    print( "f1" )
    def f2():
        print( "f2" )

#f1.f2()
```

more explain:
by this link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154634/call-nested-function-in-python`  its work with this code:

```
def f1():
    print( "f1" )
    def f2():
        print( "f2" )
    f1.f2 = f2

f1()
f1.f2()
```

is there anyway to cal f2 directly. without call f1 first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call Nested Function in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154634/call-nested-function-in-python)

Comment: No, there is not. Just like you can't specify a file without giving its full path. How would the computer know where to look for it? If you want `f2` in the outer scope, just put it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call f2 until you have executed f1 at least once because until f1 is executed, f2 doesn't exist. It is the action of executing the code of f1 that causes f2 to be created as a function and then become callable.

In Java, class or method definitions are created at compile time, which allows you to access them without having executed the parent container. Not true with Python.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible.

The function `f2` is defined within `f1`. It is not defined until `f1` has been called.

```
In [1]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:def f1():
:    print( "f1" )
:    def f2():
:        print( "f2" )
:--

In [2]: f1()
f1

In [3]: f2()
--------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-fdec4c1c071f> in <module>()
----> 1 f2()

NameError: name 'f2' is not defined

In [4]: f1.f2()
--------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-3af025f48622> in <module>()
----> 1 f1.f2()

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'f2'
```

It cannot be called outside of `f1`, the name `f2` is not defined outside the scope of `f1`.

Comment: It's not really a scope issue.  The ``f2`` doesn't get created until ``f1`` is called.

Comment: But even after `f1` has been called, you still can't call `f2` from outside of `f1`. Isn't that scope?

Comment: That would be a second problem; however, the OP said he wasn't even going to call ``f1``, so the functions never exists to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

The *f2()* function is created by the call to *f1()*.

So, no you can't call *f2* without *f1* because it doesn't exist yet :-)