# Importing a function inside another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-import

Lets say that I have a script, `test.py`, that has a function that it within another function:

```
 x = 3
 def function_1(x):
     ...
     y = x + 7

     def function_2():
        return value
```

Now I want to use both `function_1` and `function_2` in another script. How do I do that?

I've tried this:

```
import test
from test import function_1
from function_1 import function_2
```

I basically just get an error saying `No module named function_1`. It does import `function_1` and I can use it, but not `function_2`. I can't just make `function_1` a class (it needs a parameter). How can I fix this? Can I somehow use `_main_` to replace `function_1`? Could I then import just `function_2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call Nested Function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154634/call-nested-function-in-python)

Comment: Originally, they were not nested. But I was trying to runt the full script (everything within function_1) within another script. The easiest way I could figure out how to do that was make the entire script a function, import the script, and call the function inside the other script. So, to clarify, 1) How can I call my full script(`test.py`) inside another script and, 2) then call just `function_2`? I think if I can do #1, I can do #2.

Comment: When you import the entire script is run. You can just define `function_2` in the global namespace, and then call it in the script somewhere.

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your update. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nested function `function_2` is an object in the *local* namespace of the outer function. It doesn't even exist as a function when `function_1` is not running.

Normally, a nested function either performs a *private* computation for the outer function, or gets returned in some form or another. In the latter case, you can run `function_1` to get a reference to `function_2`.

Any object that you want to import should be in the global namespace, or at least directly referenceable from it. A better design would be

```
x = 3

def function_1(x):
    y = x + 7
    # Do some stuff, including using function_2
    return y

def function_2(value):
    # Do some stuff
    return value
```

And keep in mind that *defining* a function is not the same as *running* it. As a corollary, the `x` inside `function_1` is not the same as the `x` that you set to 3 at the module level.

**Update for your update**

You absolutely can make `function_1` into a class, and make `function_2` a method of it:

```
class function_1:
    def __call__(self, x):
        y = x + 7
        value = self.function_2(y)
        return y, value

    @staticmethod
    def function_2(value):
        return value
```

In this case you could do the following in your other script:

```
from test import function_1

f1 = function_1()
# Call it:
f1(7)
# Call function_2:
function_1.function_2('blah')
# Or alternatively:
f1.function_2('foo')
```