# I want to call function in other function python

Tags: python

Question is simple. I just want to call function2 in this code. How can ı do? so I want to print text in this code.

```
def func1():
    def func2():
        print("test")
```

Comment: You can only call `function2` when inside of `function1` (unless you explicitly make it available outside), and in that case, it's like any other function call. Please give more detail about how you expect it to be used.

Comment: You want to call `func2` from inside `func1` or from outside?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Nested Function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154634/call-nested-function-in-python)

Comment: That is not [easily] possible, or a good idea. Because `func2` is no longer required only locally, you should encapsulate `func1` and `func2` inside a either class or module so that they exist within an appropriate scope.

Comment: This should be easily possible via a number of ways (making it a "static" function of the function, returning the function, assigning it to a global, making the function a custom callable class...). Which way is appropriate for them depends on their use case though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need:

```py
def func1():
    def func2():
        print("test")
    func2()
```

And then call func1:

```py
>>> func1()
test
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need exactly you wrote:

```
def f1():
    def f2():
        print("test")
    f2()
f1()
```

But maybe you meant a class:

```
class c:
    def f():
        print("f()")
```