# How to access a class METHODS within static/class methods?

Tags: class, instance, python-3.5, static-methods, class-method

`
class A(object):
    x = 0

```
def say_hi(self):
    pass

@staticmethod
def say_hi_static():
    pass

@classmethod
def say_hi_class(cls):
    pass

def run_self(self):
    self.x += 1
    print(self.x) # outputs 1
    self.say_hi()
    self.say_hi_static()
    self.say_hi_class()

@staticmethod
def run_static():
    print(A.x)  # outputs 0
    # A.say_hi() #  wrong
    A.say_hi_static()
    A.say_hi_class()

@classmethod
def run_class(cls):
    print (cls.x)# outputs 0
    # cls.say_hi() #  wrong
    cls.say_hi_static()
    cls.say_hi_class()
```

`

> > > A.run_static()
> > >       0
> > >
> > > A.run_class()
> > >       0
> > >       a=A()
> > >
> > > a.run_class()
> > >       0
> > >
> > > a.run_static()
> > >       0

Above code explain how to access class variable within static & class methods... 
   **What if I want to access methods' variable within static & class methods**

Comment: You can't. You are confusing aspects of classes (which have methods associated with them, which you can access with the "dot" syntax) and functions (whose inner functions are literally private to them). However, I think that there is no reason for you to have nested `mysub` inside of `myadd` here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why do you have `mysub` nested?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's similar to the way local variables work. The `mysub` function is only defined for the purpose of the `myadd` function and only exists there

Comment: You are acessing method of returned value, so In Your case its int

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing a function within a function(nested function?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054228/accessing-a-function-within-a-functionnested-function)

Comment: Please use markdown syntax.

Comment: Sorry, Will use markdown from next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to define the function mysub as a [staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod), so you can use it as an "independent" function:

```
class Myclass1(object):
    def __init__(self,d):#, dict_value):
        self.d=d
    def myadd(self):
        b=2
        return b

    @staticmethod
    def mysub(u):  #Note that self is not an argument!
        a=u
        print('A value:',a)
        return a     


Instance=Myclass1(1)    # Created an instance
Instance.mysub(1)

# ('A value:', 1)
# Out[42]: 1
```