# How to call a method which is inside a class method in Python

Tags: python-3.x, oop, scope

I'm new to OOP concepts and I have trouble understanding the scope of this tricky code. Below is my code,  I want to access SomeClass.someMethod() in SomeOtherClass.someOtherMethod(). Is this possible? If so how? Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
class SomeClass:
    def method1(self):
         print("Hi Hello")
    def method2(self):
         print("Hello how are you?")
         def someMethod(name):
             print(f"Hi {name}")
         someMethod("Max")

class SomeOtherClass(SomeClass):
   def someOtherMethod(self):
        print(1+2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `super()`, please google on it.

```
class SomeClass:
    def method1(self):
        print("Hi Hello")
    def method2(self):
        print("Hello how are you?")
        def someMethod(name):
            print(f"Hi {name}")
        someMethod("Max")

class SomeOtherClass(SomeClass):
    def someOtherMethod(self):
        print(1+2)
    
    def get(self):
        super().method2()

t = SomeOtherClass()
t.get()
```

However, inner method: `someMethod` cannot be accessed outside unless executed inside `method2`.

Please have a look:

[Accessing a function within a function(nested function?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054228/accessing-a-function-within-a-functionnested-function)

**As an addition:**

You may also need to learn something about `Method Order Resolution`, please search on it.